# javascript var value with redirecting url getting null

Tags: javascript, jsp

In javascript i am getting true or false but getting null when adding variable with url in controller. My code is like

```
function validate() {

var prodVisible = $('#ProdTab').is(':visible');

window.open('${fileOpenOnPath}localFileUpload.htm?Id=${seVO.id}&prodVisible=${prodVisible}')
}
```

in controller i am getting null value of prodVisible.

Comment: What is `productionTab` ?

Comment: productionTab is a div. I am getting true or false in prodVisible variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand correct, you are trying to mix javascript with jsp.

The `${prodVisible}` is a jsp variable (server side) and `prodVisible` is a javascript variable (client side).

The server side code is executed first, so `${prodVisible}` will always be null.

What you want is

```
window.open('${fileOpenOnPath}localFileUpload.htm?Id=${seVO.id}&prodVisible=' + prodVisible)
```

Answer (score 0):

try by removing is visible from variable

```
var prodVisible = $('#ProdTab')
```

Comment: I am checking visibility by visible

Comment: default it is visible i think

Comment: I need true or false so it returns

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the value of `prodVisible` right?

so your code should be like this.

```js
var prodVisible = $('#ProdTab').is(':visible');
window.open('${fileOpenOnPath}localFileUpload.htm?Id=${seVO.id}&prodVisible=${prodVisible}');
```

and get value of `prodVisible` from controller.

Comment: Yes I want to pass prodVisible value. but getting null value in cantroller